# Draw diagonal line from corner to corner inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, css, xml, draw

I'm new in Android development and I'm trying to draw a line inside my yellow RelativeLayout from bottom left corner to top right corner. 
I've added a `layer-list` - `diagonal_line`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:top="300dp"
    android:bottom="-300dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-300dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-10"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="line"
            android:top="1dip" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#000" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

then to `styles`

```
<style name="diagonalStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/diagonal_line</item>
</style>
```

then added it to my `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@style/diagonalStyle"
android:background="#FFDC7F">
```

My problem is that if I add the color the line is not showing and without color the line appears but is not in the correct position. Perhaps this question is a duplicate but please be gentle, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: instead of `android:background="#FFDC7F"` use `android:backgroundTint="#FFDC7F"` in your relative layout.

Comment: I cannot use backgroundTint, instead I found a solution to add the background, I've added a new item inside diagonal_line xml. But the line position is still wrong. I don't know how to position it correctly :(

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) path to draw line inside yellow `RelativeLayout` from bottom left corner to top right corner. Your `diagonal_line.xml` should be like (assume line color is blue `#0000FF` and line width is `4`):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:height="64dp"
        android:width="64dp"
        android:viewportHeight="600"
        android:viewportWidth="600" >

    <path
        android:name="diagonal_line"
        android:strokeColor="#0000FF"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:pathData="M600, 0 l-600, 600z" />
</vector>
```

(absolute dimensions not important, because vector will be rescaled for `RelativeLayout` size). Your `styles.xml` should include section

```
<style name="diagonalStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/diagonal_line</item>
</style>
```

as you wrote, and in case you cannot use `backgroundTint` in your `{your_layout}.xml` file, you should set solid colored background (`android:background="#FFDC7F"`) for your `Relativelayout` and put "dummy" `View` with `diagonalStyle` (`style="@style/diagonalStyle"`) over it. Something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFDC7F"
    tools:context="{YOUR_CONTEXT}">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/diagonalStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As result, you should give something like that:

[image: Diagonal stroked layout]

More path tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e).