# Is there a way to make a drawable or a custom view with a diagonal line in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-custom-view, drawable

Well, I want to do a drawable or a custom view like this. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? I could not find. Ignore the "12:00", i just want to do an background with this diagonal line.

[image]

Comment: You can make a line ShapeDrawable defined in XML: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape

Comment: Yes, but I want a background with a diagonal line over it, you know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48282997/506796 Looks like VectorDrawable is more sensible than ShapeDrawable if you want a diagonal line. You can set your drawable as the background of any view.

Comment: Yes, I used something like that along with @AbdullahNoor's response and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f5f5f5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="25"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="25">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#e0e0e0" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: You forgot to put the background, but I have already managed and edited your response. Thank you very much, it helped me a lot!!!!!